# Do conversions to binary files in C++ contain text to show there is stuff in them?

Tags: c++, binaryfiles

I am working on a project where I need to first convert the binary file to a char array then swap the casing for each letter, then add the changed array to another output file. However, when I read the binary file data, it returns an empty array, so nothing was being passed to the swap function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main( )
{
  char *buf;
  string str1 = "abababab";

  int size1 = (str1.size());

  ofstream output ("output.txt", ios::out | ios::binary);

  output.write(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&size1), sizeof(int));
  output.write(str1.c_str(), size1);

  output.flush();
  output.close();

  return 0;
}
```

My problem is the file `output.txt` contains text characters, as follows:

```
^H^@^@^@abababab
```

Is this still a binary file at this point, and if I have a program read each set of bytes, will it output them correctly?

Comment: The code to read this would first read the size, then read that number of bytes into a string.  Should work fine.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but you don't need `output.flush()` or `output.close();`. The destructor will do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> My problem is the file `output.txt` contains text characters, as follows `^H^@^@^@abababab`

That is expected: you wrote an `int` first (presumably of 4 bytes) which is the `^H^@^@^@` portion, and then the string.

> Is this still a binary file at this point

All files are binary. "Text files" are just a way to say the contents follow some text encoding, like UTF-8.

> if I have a program read each set of bytes, will it output them correctly?

If you are asking whether it is a problem saving bytes that are not text: no, it is not a problem.

Comment: @ADS_Fibonacci `^H^@^@^@` represents the bytes `08 00 00 00`, which is the binary form of integer 8 on your machine, ie the character length of your string `"abababab"`

Comment: Then the text I am seeing in `output.txt` containing the only the binary form of the characters, and not appending the text forms of them as well?

Comment: @ADS_Fibonacci there's no text form. All files are binary but some binary files encode characters based on some encoding. To analyze binary files you should use a hex editor instead. If you use `vi` it'll translate the non-displayable characters to Ctrl code like `^H^@^@^@`